# breaking and stiching of image after image prediction

Tags: patch

I have a trained model to test images of 256x256 size only. But I have to test very big images of higher resolution, for example, 2048x2048.
This can be done while virtually dividing the image into non-overlapping patches of 256x256 and then predicting them by one by one, and then stitching them back to the full image, and then have to calculate the metrics comparing original and final ...
I am not able to make python code for this. Can somebody help